# write command in interactive prompt (powershell or bat)

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I work in program with interactive prompt call `XDIAL`
I want write `*select * from pcastd*` in this prompt like this

```
 D:\Aither\Exe\xdial.exe  
 start-sleep-seconds 1
/C "select * from pcastd"
```

[xdial interactive prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrKgC.png)

there is not `"select * from pcastd"` writed ...

how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to interactive input, command-line utilities typically accept input via the *pipeline*, which sends an input command's output to the target utility's *stdin* (standard input):

Therefore, you can echo the string of interest and pipe it to `xdial.exe`:

```bsh
# From PowerShell
'select * from pcastd' | xdial.exe
```

```
REM # From cmd.exe
REM # Note that there's no space before the "|" by design,
REM # because a space would become part of `echo`'s output.
echo select * from pcastd| xdial.exe
```